# Entity Framework 4.0 CTP5 Many to Many relation ship with a help table?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, ora-00942

i have a question about EF4 again  :) sorry i can't find any thing on the net.

The question is i am using CTP5 Code Only to map (many to many), how do i do it???

But i am doing the old fashion way, i mean i have three tables:

1. Users
2. Companies.
3. UsersToCompanies -> (UserId, CompanyId)

How do i map this, it will be really appreciated if you would show me the code example to it,
from POCO's to Mapping.

---

[image]

This is the error i receive...

```
This is my entities
public class User 
{
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public int? UserRoleId { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public string UserPassword { get; set; }
   public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
   public virtual UserRole UserRole { get; set; }

   //this is my many to many prop
   public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
   public int CompanyId { get; set; }
   public string CompanyNameHe { get; set; }
   public string CompanyNameEn { get; set; }
   public string CompanyParent { get; set; }
   public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }

   //this is my many to many prop
   public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

/*relationship map*/
public class UsersCompanies
{
   public int Id { get; set; } 
   public int UserId { get; set; } 
   public int CompanyId { get; set; } 
}
    //mapping
 public class CompanyMap :  BaseConfig<Company>
 {
    public CompanyMap()
    {
        /*Identity*/
        HasKey(c => c.CompanyId);
        Property(c => c.CompanyId).HasDatabaseGenerationOption(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity).HasColumnName("COMPANY_ID");

        /*Have default values*/
        Property(c => c.InsertDate).HasDatabaseGenerationOption(DatabaseGenerationOption.Computed).HasColumnName("INSERT_DATE");

        /*simple scalars*/
        Property(c => c.CompanyNameHe).HasMaxLength(32).IsRequired().HasColumnName("COMPANY_NAME_HE");
        Property(c => c.CompanyNameEn).HasMaxLength(32).IsRequired().HasColumnName("COMPANY_NAME_EN");
        Property(c => c.CompanyParent).HasMaxLength(32).IsRequired().HasColumnName("COMPANY_PARENT");
        ToTable("CMS_COMPANY", "GMATEST");
    }
 }


public class UserMap : BaseConfig<User>
{
   public UserMap()
   {
       /*Identity*/
       HasKey(c => c.UserId);
       Property(c => c.UserId).HasDatabaseGenerationOption(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity).HasColumnName("USER_ID");

       /*Have default values*/
       Property(c => c.InsertDate).HasDatabaseGenerationOption(DatabaseGenerationOption.Computed).HasColumnName("INSERT_DATE");

       /*simple scalars*/
       Property(c => c.UserName).HasMaxLength(25).IsRequired().HasColumnName("USER_NAME");
       Property(c => c.UserPassword).HasMaxLength(25).IsRequired().HasColumnName("USER_PASSWORD");
       Property(c => c.UserRoleId).IsRequired().HasColumnName("USER_ROLE_ID");

       /*relationship*/
       HasRequired(u => u.UserRole).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.UserRoleId);


       HasMany(p => p.Companies).WithMany(c => c.Users).Map(mc =>
       {
           mc.ToTable("UsersCompanies");
           mc.MapLeftKey(p => p.UserId, "CompanyId");
           mc.MapRightKey(c => c.CompanyId, "UserId");
       });
       ToTable("CMS_USERS", "GMATEST");
   }
}

public class UsersCompaniesMap : BaseConfig<UsersCompanies>
{
   public UsersCompaniesMap()
   {
       /*Identity*/
       HasKey(k => k.Id);
       Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGenerationOption(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity).HasColumnName("ID");

       Property(c => c.UserId).IsRequired().HasColumnName("USER_ID");
       Property(c => c.CompanyId).IsRequired().HasColumnName("COMPANY_ID");

       ToTable("CMS_USERS_TO_COMPANIES", "GMATEST");
   }
}
```

---

Here's the error I get:

> '((new
>   System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView(ctx.FindAll())).Items[0]).Companies'
>   threw an exception of type
>   'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException'
>
> Inner exception: ORA-00942: table or
>   view does not exist

Comment: Please don't add an answer in order to add content to your question.  You can use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5210506/edit) link to do this.  You can also leave comments on questions within your own question (any question/answer at 50 rep) to notify people of updates.

Comment: Also, you're using this against Oracle?  Ugh.  Its obvious from the exception that almost none of what you added is useful to your issue.  You've got a connection/database/security issue.  You need to double and triple check your connection strings and your database.  Also, [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189557/ora-00942-table-or-view-does-not-exist-how-do-i-find-which-table-or-view-it-is); it is Java but the same error.  If you were using sql server I'd tell you to spin up Profiler and watch the connection and queries; don't know the oracle equivalent.

Comment: I don't think it's an Oracle issue, it's more a not correct configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for my problem, i have to say many thanks to you all, but Andrey from Devart,
have given me the solution, it's simple.

First off all i have to have, three tables Companies, Users, UsersCompanies/

Second off all i have to map the tables to original names of tables example:
my users table called in Db like that: CMS_USERS i have to map it with original name.
this is the example that i use and it's really works.

```
HasMany(c => c.Companies)
          .WithMany(u => u.Users)
          .Map(mc =>
          {
              mc.ToTable("CMS_USERS_TO_COMPANIES", "GMATEST");
              mc.MapLeftKey(c => c.UserId, "USER_ID");
              mc.MapRightKey(u => u.CompanyId, "COMPANY_ID");
          });
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You do not really need 3 tables to perform the mapping. You could simply do the following:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And this should do it. As long as you have a virtual ICollection referencing the other entity in both POCO's, CTP5's conventions should take care of everything for you. On the other hand, if you prefer doing it manually using the Fluent API, then check [this blog by the ADO.NET team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/14/ef-feature-ctp5-fluent-api-samples.aspx) (scroll a little down to the many-to-many relationship section)